# Show only some specific values in the select (laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 public function create()
{
    $exam_id = Exam::pluck('id')->all();
    $exams = Exam::pluck('id','level')->all();
    $users = User::pluck('name','id')->all();
    $dateExams = Date_Exam::where('exam_id', '=', $exam_id)
                            ->select('date')
                            ->get();

    return view('exam_reservations.create', compact('exam_id','exams','users','dateExams'));
}
```

I am trying to show only some dates from the database filtered by the select control. I would like to click in an specific exam and get all the dates available for it. Not all dates for the different exams.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue that you are facing? Are you not getting the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t explain well. The problem is when I select an exam (B2 First Cambrigde English Exam) and try to select the dates available for this specific exam, all dates from the rest of the exam appears as well. I just want to filter my result by exam.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, maybe you could edit it to clarify so ppl have a better chance of understanding and helping.  If you are trying to filter `Date_Exam` records  by exam ID, `Date_Exam::where('exam_id', $exam_id)->get()` is enough.

Comment: Thanks. It didn´t work. I have been looking for some information and what I need is a Dynamic Dependant Select Box using JQuery Ajax.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Laravel ... as I said, you will have better luck getting help if you can edit your question and clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use eloquent or query builder 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects

```
Exam::select('name',,'date')->get();
or 
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, pal for your time. I didn´t explain well. The problem is when I select an exam (B2 First Cambrigde English Exam) and try to select the dates available for this specific exam, all dates from the rest of the exam appears as well. I just want to filter my result by exam.